# How to use Autoware's lidar_camera extrinsics

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the readme [autoware.readthedocs.io](https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/sensing/autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator.html) and have performed the intrinsic calibration and also the extrinsic calibration successfully and left with a file similar to YYYYmmdd_HHMM_autoware_lidar_camera_calibration.yaml.

The docs in the end mention "*This file can be used with Autoware's  Calibration Publisher to publish and register the transformation between the LiDAR and camera. The file contains both the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.*"

However, I am not sure how to use this file. The calibration_publisher uses only the intrinsics file. Where and how is the extrinsics file used? Do I just replace the intrinsics file path with the extrinsics file path? I intend to register the lidar2camera_tf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366199/how-to-use-autoware%27s-lidar_camera-extrinsics/) by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 459 on 2020-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The extrinsic parameters should be with the intrinsic parameter in a single file if you follow the [instructions here](https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/sensing/autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator.html#camera-lidar-extrinsic-calibration). The structure of the file should be like [this one](https://github.com/lgsvl/autoware-data/blob/master/GoMentum/data/calibration/camera_lidar_3d/prius/nic-150407.yml), but with your specific calibration data.

The calibration publisher node will [read the extrinsic parameters](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/utilities/blob/143131cc9892ae291292d413437d3af465a602d7/calibration_publisher/src/calibration_publisher.cpp#L196) and [register a transform](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/utilities/blob/143131cc9892ae291292d413437d3af465a602d7/calibration_publisher/src/calibration_publisher.cpp#L244) between the camera and lidar coordinates with it.

---

Originally posted by [pedroexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/51367/pedroexe/) with karma: 50 on 2021-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-02-26**:
Thanks! I will try this out and give you an update.

**Comment by [Thiago de Borba](https://answers.ros.org/users/63996/thiago-de-borba/) on 2021-05-28**:
Hi @Akhil Kurup,

Could you calibrate it correctly?

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-05-28**:
Not yet! My project and priorities have changed and I am unable to spend time with it

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-05-31**:
Thanks for the clarification @pedroexe! It works now. My issue was with topic names. After fixing those, I can see a "calibrated" link between the lidar and camera on the tf tree

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-05-31**:
@Thiago de Borba I got it to work now. As I mentioned, the tools were performing normally. My issue was with topic names and namespaces

**Comment by [Thiago de Borba](https://answers.ros.org/users/63996/thiago-de-borba/) on 2021-06-01**:
But for me the calibration extrinsics is complelty wrong. Is it working fine for you?

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-06-01**:
Ahh yes! With help from @djchopp here are a couple lessons learnt:

1. The transform generated is from lidar_frame -> camera_frame. So make the appropriate change in the launch file.
2. When you select points in RViz, it publishes to the /clickedpoint topic in **your global fixed frame in rviz**. What I did was to **change it to the lidar_frame before selecting points**. That way, the generated extrinsics were relative to the lidar.
3. After all is said and done, be sure to change the camera_frame to the newly published calibrated_frame in the camera launch file.